# Sum of positive i.i.d. random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, $ be i.i.d. random variables with $X_1 > 0$. Let $S_n = \sum_{m=1}^n X_m$. Can we conclude $[\sup_{n \ge 1} S_n = \infty$] almost surely?

Assuming the statement is true, by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, $[\sup_{n \ge 1} S_n = \infty]$ has probability either $0$ or $1$, so it is enough to show that this event has positive probability. But how can we prove this without knowing the distribution of $X_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_1\gt0$ almost surely, then there exists $x\gt0$ such that $P(X_1\geqslant x)\gt0$. Thus, $S_n\geqslant xN_n$ where $N_n=\#\{k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n, X_k\geqslant x\}$. The series $\sum\limits_nP(X_n\geqslant x)=\sum\limits_nP(X_1\geqslant x)$ diverges hence, by Borel-Cantelli, $X_k\geqslant x$ for infinitely many $k$ almost surely, that is, $N_n\to\infty$ almost surely. In other words, $P(S_n\to\infty)=1$.